# Encoding order of numbers in an ascending set of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say I have a set of numbers $14,2,8,7$ and I want to send them to my friend in the correct order, but to be sent I have to put them through a filter, that filter is going to sort them into ascending order ($2,7,8,14$) which would be incorrect. Is there some way I can either add numbers to the set or modify the original numbers to encode the order into them, without dramatically increasing the size of the numbers or the number of numbers.

I am only dealing with positive integers, and in my specific situation, I only need to encode 4-32 numbers between 255-32. I would prefer them to not become too large (More than double their original number) or to add too many numbers to the set (More than double the original length of the set)

I already have my own solution but I want to see more.

My Solution: Take the position and turn it into binary and append it to the original number, this would result in $4$ ($0010$) in the 3rd position ($10$) in the set turning into $34$ ($100010$)

(Note: For more examples see Gerry Myerson's solutions answered below)

Comment: Although you haven't said so, I'm going to assume the "numbers" in question are positive integers. You can encode $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ as $a_1,a_1+a_2,\dots,a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$. Your friend gets $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ and decodes it as $b_1,b_2-b_1,\dots,b_n-b_{n-1}$. E.g., $6,1,2,7$ encodes as $6,7,9,16$, and $6,7,9,16$ decodes as $6,7-6,9-7,16-9$ which is $6,1,2,7$. Simples!

Comment: Luckily I’m only dealing with positive integers, no floating point numbers and no negative numbers.

Comment: Liam, the filter is destroying information, which means that you can't possibly restore the deleted information without it costing you some bits. So if the original numbers can be in the range $1-32$, using five bits per number, the encoded numbers must necessarily use more than five bits each.

Comment: And in fact the total number of extra bits you need to send $n$ numbers is $\lceil \log_2 (n!)\rceil$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The problem with that is say I have 255,255,255,255 it’ll get encoded as 255,510,1020,2040 which means the numbers are way higher than I would like, even if I split them up it still results in high numbers: 127,127,127,127,127,127,127,127 -> 127,254,508,1016,2032,4064,8128,16256

Comment: Also remember your not limited to changing the value, you can in addition add more numbers in the set. I would much prefer having 10 or 20 more numbers than having numbers stretching into the thousands

Comment: $255,255,255,255$ encodes as $255,510,765,1020$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry doing maths in my head at 11pm. My brain saw it and thought it was exponentially increasing.

Comment: Encode $6,1,2,7$ as $6,1,2,7,10,11,13,17$. The filter turns this into $1,2,6,7,10,11,13,17$. Now $10-7=3$, $11-10=1$, $13-11=2$, and $17-13=4$, and that sequence of differences, $3,1,2,4$, tells your friend how to unscramble $1,2,6,7$; take the third number, then the first, then the second, then the fourth; $6,1,2,7$. Voila! (11pm? – you and I must be in the same time zone)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Wow that works perfectly! thanks! (Also AEST, Australian Eastern Standard Time, I’m in Melbourne)

Comment: Can this be reopened as I have edited it to be more clear?

Comment: By editing, Liam, you have caused it to enter a review queue; now sit back and wait to see whether the reviewers decide to reopen. There's another step you can take, but first wait to see what the reviewers do. I'm in Sydney. You Melbournians are doing it tough these days. My commiserations.

Answer (score 2):

The question having been reopened, I'll elevate my comments to an answer.

First method. Encode $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ as $a_1,a_1+a_2,\dots,a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$. For example, $6,1,2,7$ encodes as $6,7,9,16$. The encoded sequence is already increasing, so the filter passes it to the friend unchanged. The friend, receiving $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$, retrieves the original sequence as $b_1,b_2-b_1,\dots,b_n-b_{n-1}$. In the example, $6,7,9,16$ decodes as $6,7-6,9-7,16-9$ which is $6,1,2,7$, as we wanted. The advantage of this method is that we don't increase the length of the sequence; the disadvantage is that the last term in the encoded sequence, $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$, can be considerably larger than the terms we started with.

Second method. Let $\max\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}=m$. Encode $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ as $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n,b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ where the $b_i$ are chosen so that the numbers $b_1-m,b_2-b_1,\dots,b_n-b_{n-1}$ encode the information needed to undo the effect of the filter on $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$. This is easier to understand by looking at our example:

We encode $6,1,2,7$ as $6,1,2,7,10,11,13,17$. The filter turns this into $1,2,6,7,10,11,13,17$. The friend calculates $10-7=3$, $11-10=1$, $13-11=2$, $17-13=4$, and then uses these differences $3,1,2,4$ to unscramble the received $1,2,6,7$ by writing the 3rd term, then the 1st, then the 2nd, then the 4th; $6,1,2,7$.

The second method has the disadvantage of making the sequence twice as long, but the advantage of not making the numbers that much larger.